# Change path of template file in ember router

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli, javascriptmvc

My router looks like this at the moment:

```
Router.map(function() {
    this.route('item1');
    this.route('item2');
    this.route('item3', function(){
        this.route('sub-item', { path: '/sub-item' });
    });
});
```

And my templates folder looks like this:

[image]

Now when I have a hyperlink like:

```
{{link-to 'Sub Item' 'item3.sub-item'}}
```

This navigates to the `sub-item.hbs` inside the `item3` folder. How can I change the path of the nested `sub-item` route so that it renders the `sub-item.hbs` file in the `templates` folder instead? I tried changing it to `this.route('sub-item', { path: '../sub-item' });` but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to reset the namespace `this.route('sub-item', { path: '/sub-item', resetNamespace: true });` and move the `item3/sub-item.hbs` to `sub-item/index.hbs`.

And your link to path becomes `{{link-to 'Sub Item' 'sub-item.index'}}` `sub-item` if you want to preserve the active class that ember automatically adds to links.

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the answer. Actually what I'm trying to achieve is for the `item3.sub-item` route to display the file in the physical location `templates\sub-item.hbs`, instead of displaying the one in `templates\item3\sub-item.hbs`

Comment: @JeevanJose the route will remain nested, you just need to reset the namespace so the resolver can fetch the correct files, it doesn't load `sub-item.hbs` now since you aren't in the `sub-item` route